My Xampp exe file is not showing up and I'm unable to connect with the xampp control panel
Today, When I restarted my pc I was unable to find my xampp exe and unable to open my control panel. I tried finding the exe file to directly start my control panel but it was not there. How can I recover it.
I tried finding it through the run using C://xampp/xampp-control.ini and C://xampp/xampp-control.exe but i did not find the file
